# Can't figure out why I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, null, nsinputstream

I keep getting this error :

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and cannot figure out how to debug it!

Here's my code :

```
func readCSV() -> Array<String> {

    // Creates a new array of strings
    var csvArray : Array<String> = Array<String>()

    if let url: NSURL = NSURL(string : "URLFROMCSV" ) {
        // Creates an Input Stream that will load the datas from our URL
        let data :NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
            let stream : NSInputStream! = NSInputStream(data: data)

            // Opens the receiving stream
            stream.open()

            // Sets a buffer with a given size size
            let bufferSize = 1024
            var buffer  = Array <UInt8>(count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)

            // String variable initialization
            var csvFullString : String = ""

            // While the stream receives datas, parses datas, convert them into strings and then concatenate them into one big string
            while (stream.hasBytesAvailable) {

                let readSize = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
                let csvRaw = NSString (bytes: &buffer, length: readSize, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let csvString = csvRaw as String!

                csvFullString = csvFullString + csvString

            }

            // Fills the array with each strings. Separation between strings is made when a Θ character is parsed
            csvArray = csvFullString.componentsSeparatedByString("Θ")

            // Delete each null string
            for(var i = 0 ; i < csvArray.count; i++) {
                if(csvArray[i] == "") {

                    csvArray.removeAtIndex(i)

                }
            }
        }

    return csvArray

}
```

After searching on the web, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with unwrapping elements but the fact is when I debug it, i don't get any nil value anywhere.

PS: Would like to upload a screen but can't because i don't have 10 reputation, so bad!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** : Line  let data :NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)! got the error.
Terry

Comment: So you choose not to reveal which line got the error??

Comment: Somehow I don't think you did a very thorough google search...

Comment: Sorry the  let data :NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)! line got the error. And yes i've done google research but I can't handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably creating the error in one of these two lines (though it may show up later):

```
let data :NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
let stream : NSInputStream! = NSInputStream(data: data)
```

You're assigning an optional value to an implicitlyUnwrappedOptional type and then using it without checking if you have a valid value.

This is why `if let` exists. It's a little funny that you've started to indent as if you're using `if let` but aren't.

Try this instead:

```
if let url = NSURL(string : "http://gorillaapplications.com/etablissements.csv" ) {

    // Creates an Input Stream that will load the datas from our URL
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        let stream = NSInputStream(data: data)
        stream.open()
        // rest of your code here
    }
    else {
        println("Didn't get a data object")
    }
}
else {
    println("Didn't get a URL object")
}
```

You really need to grasp Optionals for Swift. I'd recommend reading my Optionals chapter in this iBook: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-optionals-generics-for/id943445214?mt=11&uo=4&at=11lMGu

**Update:**

Since you added a bit more in your comments above, you're saying you get the error on this line: `let data: NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!`. This is because of the `!` at the end, which tells Swift you're sure that this function will return a valid value, so just use it, without checking if it's `nil` first. In your case, the function is returning `nil` and so your app crashes. Using the sample code I've provided above, you'll see that you'll no longer get a crash, but your code will execute the `"Didn't get a data object"` line. You'll need to correctly handle the case where you can't load data from that URL.

Comment: Thank you for answering Dave. The problem I have with the example code you gave me is that it says that the bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type when it comes to if let stream = NSInputStream(data: data) so I can't run it as it, I have to modify it to a non conditional binding but it keeps getting me errors. 

By the way thank you for the answer, as a beginner I'm really happy to hear from advanced users.

Comment: @TerryVogelsang Ah sorry, `NSInputStream` doesn't return an optional, fixed the sample code for you.

Comment: Ok thank you! So now I get the message "didn't get a data object" it doesn't crash my app anymore but I still have no idea why the data object is not creating, the url is a csv file and appears as it when i hover the variable url and click on the eye.

Comment: @TerryVogelsang Well that's a different question, one you could create on StackOverflow. When I run that code in a playground, it does load the data from your URL. Is it possible you have a firewall or some other network issue preventing you from accessing the URL from your test device? It is connected via Wifi etc? Try executing `curl http://gorillaapplications.com/etablissements.csv` in a terminal window on your machine to ensure you see what you think you'll see.

Comment: I get the thing i want when i run this command in mac terminal but i don't know why i doesn't work in Xcode. Playground also outputs me the didn't get a data object string though... Sooner in the afternoon it worked but since I finished the class, i doesn't work anymore. weird...

Comment: Just restarted my computer and it works! I have no idea where it was coming from but it works perfectly now! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Excellent. If the answer helped, please don't forget to up vote it!